# Can I use Easy Transfer twice?

Tags: windows, windows-easy-transfer

I used Easy Transfer to migrate files from my Vista machine to a new Windows 7 machine. However, I have delayed in using the new machine about 2 months so now my old Vista machine has new files and information not transferred to the new machine. Can I run Easy Transfer again to pick up the incremental changes? Or something else?